# Ubuntu 23.04 built-in monitor and external monitor proportion is wrong

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, external-monitor

I just installed Ubuntu 23.04 on my new laptop (Asus vivobook 14").

When I connect my external monitor (AOC 27B1H 27"), it seems like Ubuntu gets the monitor sizes wrong - monitor 1 - built-in 14", monitor 2 - external 27":

[image: Screenshot]

I can fix the differences in display size caused by this wrong proportion by scaling up the built-in monitor display, but when I drag windows between the monitors, they jump to the far end of the monitor.

Is there any way to adjust the monitor's proportion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems all I had to do was to lower the laptop screen resolution in the display menu.